# Why Bridges don't change mac addresse of frames?

Tags: networking

I learned that router change mac address of packet with that one of its own outgoing interface, while this doesn't happen with bridges. I find it difficult to understand the logic under this implementation ,so i hope you can help me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you searched/researched this topic? Looked at web pages that explain differences between bridges, hubs, routers, and hybrid devices? The "logic" and "why"  may become clear once you understand the purpose of each different type of device.

Comment: You are  right..i'm preparing an exam of a networks course that covered a very large amount of matters in few monts, so i have still some confusion and gaps to fill ...Perhaps ,since communication by mac protocol is used inside the same logic ip network (or broadcast domain),routers (that keep separated the different ip networks linked to its interfaces ) have to replace source mac address with that of the forwarding interface got by routing table ? and this beacuase the outgoing interface of router is part of the same IP network to which belongs the next hop interface?

Comment: A note in advance: This site does not help with things like exams and assignments. For those, we encourage you to read your textbooks and/or research (internet, local library/et cetera), so that you can both learn and understand the material. However, I will be posing an answer shortly to help (both you and others) with that...

Comment: i always study from textbooks and some other material.I put questions to more expert people only when i find real difficulties to find answer to my doubts in what i read or study

Comment: For the same reason routers don't change the IP addresses on the packets and post offices don't change the address on the envelope. Because on each level, those are the addresses the forwarding is based on. Also, routers don't really change the MAC address of any frame. Instead, they unpack the L2 frame, pick out the IP packet, and then package that in whatever L2 framing is needed on the next hop. It might not be the same framing, so you can't do with just modifying some fields.

Comment: ilkkachu is being more technically correct here: Networking devices do not usually _modify_ the traffic--they pull out the important parts (frames), and then wrap that part in a new frame as needed to pass it along to the next step. Understanding the OSI networking model would be useful here to understand the how and why.

Comment: Thank you! @ilkkachu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that router change mac address of packet with that one of its own outgoing interface, while this doesn't happen with bridges

Routers work on IP packets (layer 3): to do anything, they need to unpack the lower-level frame and get the IP packet out. After they're done, they need to pack the packet to another low-level frame, suitable for the outgoing interface. That lower level frame is often an Ethernet frame, but notably, *it doesn't need to be*. One of the interfaces could be a PPP link that doesn't really use link-level addresses, or something that uses other types of link-level addresses. (PPP forms a point-to-point link, all frames are intended for the other end, so really no need for addresses.)

Forming a new Ethernet frame naturally puts the router's MAC address on as the layer 2 sender of that frame, and the next-hop router as the layer 2 recipient. But a router doesn't modify the layer 3 IP addresses on the IP packet, it keeps the source address so the eventual IP recipient knows where the packet came from and can reply, and it keeps the destination address so the next-hop router knows where to send it.

(That is, unless the router's doing NAT, which breaks the pretty picture. And it's not like routers wouldn't modify the IP packet: they need to decrease the TTL (time-to-live) field, and for IPv4, modify the checksum accordingly. And the router could do packet filtering to drop some packets, perhaps looking at the higher level headers too.)

---

So, basically it's just that layer 2 Ethernet bridges work on layer 2 Ethernet frames, forwarding based on the layer 2 MAC addresses, ignoring what's inside (but changing from one physical connection to another, e.g. twisted pair copper to fiber). Routers work on the layer 3 IP packets, forwarding based on the IP address, mostly ignoring what's inside, but changing from one layer 2 link to another. And above that, e.g. an HTTP proxy would work on the URL as roughly an "HTTP destination address", keeping that the same but forming a new lower-level "connection", with a new set of source and destination IP addresses.